# Powershell Can not click the site on Google

Tags: powershell, select, find

Hello dear friends and forum leaders

My friends have a script that does not work properly, thank you for guiding me:

This script opens an Internet Explorer browser and Google and serach "Download Music". I want to go to this page to find the nicmusic site in first page search result  and click on the site to enter the site but it does not happen !

```
$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate("https://www.google.com/search?ei=j-KLWrGyI5G2gQbN9KOQAg&q=%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF+%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%DB%8C%DA%A9&oq=%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF+%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%DB%8C%DA%A9&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.509762.515959.0.516306.23.19.1.0.0.0.358.2")
$IE.visible=$true
while($ie.busy) {sleep 5} 
$currentDocument = $ieObject.Document
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.className -eq "continue"}
$Link.click()
```

Thank you for your guidance

Sorry, English is not my first language

Comment: The variable $ieObject is never instantiated for one, so $currentDocument is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, though it's dependent on the InnerHTML property:

```
$IE = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate("https://www.google.com/search?ei=j-KLWrGyI5G2gQbN9KOQAg&q=%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF+%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%DB%8C%DA%A9&oq=%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF+%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%DB%8C%DA%A9&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.509762.515959.0.516306.23.19.1.0.0.0.358.2")
$IE.visible=$true
while($ie.busy) {sleep 5} 

$Link = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "دانلود آهنگ جدید | دانلود موزیک"}

$Link.click()
```